# call function inside class of contructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call the getWeather() inside of the constructor of the FiveDayWeather class. I am binding the function to the context of the class, but then when I try to call the function within the constructor, it errors out.

I tried:

```
this.getWeather()
```

and when that didn't work this:

```
getWeather()
```

but that didn't work either

How can I call the getWeather function from inside this class?

```
class FiveDayWeather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      days: []
    }

    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this)

    getWeather()


    console.log(this.state);
  }

  getWeather() {
    axios.get(URL)
      .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({
          days: response
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>Placeholder</div>
    )
  }
}
```

this is not about returning a response from an async call

Comment: you need an arrow function.`.then((response) => { this.setState... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your note:

> I am trying to call the getWeather() inside of the constructor

It won't work in the constructor. Put it in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method instead, like

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.getWeather();
}
```

Per your comment below, update the promise like so:

```
  getWeather() {
    axios.get(URL)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          days: response
        })
      })
  }
```

The arrow function should bind the context of `this` for you

Comment: When I do that I get the `TypeError: Cannot read property setState of undefined` which makes me think the context of this is off.